# How to integrate in Real analysis?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f \in L^1(-\infty, \infty)$. How to find the limit:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{f(x)e^{nx} dx}{1+e^{nx}}. $$
What are the difference between the integration in Riemann integral and Lebesgue integral when we compute integrations? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint 1:** Apply [dominated convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) to compute this integral. Check that all necessary conditions are satisfied.

**Hint 2:** Prove the following equality
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(x)e^{nx}}{1+e^{nx}}=
\begin{cases}
f(x)&\quad\text{ if }\quad x>0\\
0.5 f(0)&\quad\text{ if }\quad x=0\\
0&\quad\text{ if }\quad x<0\\
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1):

For a function $f$ put $f+ = f\vee 0$ and $f^- = (-f)\vee 0$.  Then $f = f^+ - f^-$.  If $\int f^+$ and $\int f^-$ are finite and $f$ is a.e. continuous, the Riemann and Lebesgue integrals agree. In particular, if $f$ is absolutely integrable in the Riemann sense,  it agrees with the Lebesgue integral.

Comment: Small nit: Riemann integrability requires (local) boundedness of the integrand.